# how can I create a WP offline environment before releasing the websites?

Tags: git, svn, github, offline

GIT? 
SVN?
WAMP?
XAMP?
MERCURIAL?
BITNAMI?

There are so many options that I am getting a bit confused.

I just want to work without publishing and a need of an internet connection, and when all is ready, just release it.

Comment: The things you listed are not the same. Only three are are servers (or server packages)-- WAMP, XAMP, and Bitnami. That is what you need. Per that [faq], questions about setting those is best posted at [sf].

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2171/wamp-vs-xampp-pros-cons-for-running-a-local-testing-server too.

Comment: @s_ha_dum, thank you both. I once did it using Xamp but I saw now a lot of things about SVN and Git and I was wondering if there is a faster way of working and installing everything offline. I saw a lot of people speaking about Git..

Comment: Git and SVN are for tracking your project's development and working with others. Unless your hosting provider supports deploying through Git, you won't be able to use it to actually release your site online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the XAMP server, I am also using the same for the last 5 years. And also you can consider to use Microsoft Web Matrix as the editor because it provides wordpress syntax highlighting, suggestions etc.

Comment: Thanks. Like I said in my last comment, I tried Xamp and I was thinking if maybe there is anything faster for developing, updating and installing.. GIT?
I saw the Webmatrix now and I've never heard about it but it is compared to Visual Stuido and Experssion web. Do you use that? I use NotePad++ but I tried Expression web and Aptana for a while.